# How to structure data in amazon dynamo db?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to store place information in dynamodb. The information is

```
id | place_name | district | state | country | latitude | longitude
```

And I want to search a place using name, district, state and country.

1. Which all indexes should be created so that I can do this efficiently?
2. Should I use a scan or a query operation?
3. Can I query table to find a place near a give latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 0):

1. It depends on what you want to query by, and what sort of combination of those attributes you want to use. It sounds more like you are looking for a search solution for this portion of your application rather than DynamoDB querying.
2. It is generally better to use `Query` over `Scan` for live application data. From the [*Query and Scan Performance* documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#ScanQueryPerformance):

   > A Scan operation always scans the entire table or secondary index, then filters out values to provide the desired result,
   >   essentially adding the extra step of removing data from the result
   >   set. Avoid using a Scan operation on a large table or index with a
   >   filter that removes many results, if possible. Also, as a table or
   >   index grows, the Scan operation slows

   Also, From the DynamoDB [*Guidelines for Query and Scan* documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#ScanQueryConsistency):

   > DynamoDB is designed for easy scalability. As a result, an application
   >   can create tables for distinct purposes, possibly even duplicating
   >   content across several tables. You want to perform scans on a table
   >   that is not taking "mission-critical" traffic. Some applications
   >   handle this load by rotating traffic hourly between two tables – one
   >   for critical traffic, and one for bookkeeping. Other applications can
   >   do this by performing every write on two tables: a "mission-critical"
   >   table, and a "shadow" table.
3. There is a system for geocoding latitude and longitude called [geohash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash), and Amazon implemented a Java library for DynamoDB that supports that. You can find some details about the library on [this blog post](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxWTJOSLE7O3J2/Geo-Library-for-Amazon-DynamoDB-Part-1-Table-Structure).